# How to handle quotients with little-oh notation?

Tags: calculus

As an example, I’m trying to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ax}{\sin bx} = \frac{a}{b}$.

Writing $\sin x = x + o(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$ (via its taylor polynomial) we have
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ax}{\sin bx} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a}{b} \frac{bx + o(x^2)}{bx + o(x^2)}$$

Im having trouble proving that the limit of the quotient on the RHS is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can factor out the desired fraction

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ax}{\sin bx} = \frac{a}{b} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{bx + o(x^2)}{bx + o(x^2)}$$

Then, on the right hand side inside the limit, factor out an $x$ in the numerator and denominator to get

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ax}{\sin bx} = \frac{a}{b} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}\frac{b + o(x)}{b + o(x)}$$

then cancel

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ax}{\sin bx} = \frac{a}{b} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{b + o(x)}{b + o(x)}$$

and you can evaluate the limit, because you no longer have a case of $\frac{0}{0}$. The limit is $1$, and you get

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ax}{\sin bx} = \frac{a}{b}$$